# Stop multithreaded Python script on Windows

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have troubles with a simple multithreaded Python looping program. It should loop infinitely and stop with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Here is an implementation using `threading`:

```
from threading import Thread, Event
from time import sleep

stop = Event()

def loop():
    while not stop.is_set():
        print("looping")
        sleep(2)

try:
    thread = Thread(target=loop)
    thread.start()
    thread.join()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("stopping")
    stop.set()
```

This MWE is extracted from a more complex code (obviously, I *do not* need multithreading to create an infinite loop).

It works as expected on Linux, but not on Windows: the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> event is not intercepted and the loop continues infinitely. According to the [Python Dev mailing list](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-August/148800.html), the different behaviors are due to the way <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is handled by the two OSs.

So, it appears that one cannot simply rely on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> with `threading` on Windows. My question is: what are the other ways to stop a multithreaded Python script on this OS with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>?

Comment: Well, obviously you can kill the task with `taskkill` (or a Python script using `os` or the third-party `psutil`, or Task Manager, Process Explorer, etc.). Is that not acceptable here?

Comment: This is correct, but I want to stop it with Ctrl+C (I updated the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by Nathaniel J. Smith in the link from your question, at least as of CPython 3.7, Ctrl-C cannot wake your main thread on Windows:

> The end result is that on Windows, control-C almost never works to
>   wake up a blocked Python process, with a few special exceptions where
>   someone did the work to implement this. On Python 2 the only functions
>   that have this implemented are time.sleep() and
>   multiprocessing.Semaphore.acquire; on Python 3 there are a few more
>   (you can grep the source for _PyOS_SigintEvent to find them), but
>   Thread.join isn't one of them.

So, what can you do?

---

One option is to just not use Ctrl-C to kill your program, and instead use something that calls, e.g., `TerminateProcess`, such as the builtin `taskkill` tool, or a Python script using the `os` module. But you don't want that.

And obviously, waiting until they come up with a fix in Python 3.8 or 3.9 or never before you can Ctrl-C your program is not acceptable.

So, the only thing you can do is not block the main thread on `Thread.join`, or anything else non-interruptable.

---

The quick&dirty solution is to just poll `join` with a timeout:

```
while thread.is_alive():
    thread.join(0.2)
```

Now, your program is briefly interruptable while it's doing the `while` loop and calling `is_alive`, before going back to an uninterruptable sleep for another 200ms. Any Ctrl-C that comes in during that 200ms will just wait for you to process it, so that isn't a problem.

Except that 200ms is already long enough to be noticeable and maybe annoying.

And it may be too short as well as too long. Sure, it's not wasting much CPU to wake up every 200ms and execute a handful of Python bytecodes, but it's not *nothing*, and it's still getting a timeslice in the scheduler, and that may be enough to, e.g., keep a laptop from going into one of its long-term low-power modes.

---

The *clean* solution is to find another function to block on. As Nathaniel J. Smith says:

> you can grep the source for _PyOS_SigintEvent to find them

But there may not be anything that fits very well. It's hard to imagine how you'd design your program to block on `multiprocessing.Semaphore.acquire` in a way that wouldn't be horribly confusing to the reader…

In that case, you might want to drag in the Win32 API directly, whether via `PyWin32` or `ctypes`. Look at how functions like `time.sleep` and `multiprocessing.Semaphore.acquire` manage to be interruptible, block on whatever they're using, and have your thread signal whatever it is you're blocking on at exit.

---

If you're willing to use undocumented internals of CPython, it looks like, at least in 3.7, the hidden `_winapi` module has [a wrapper function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_winapi.c#L1502) around [`WaitForMultipleObjects`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025(v=vs.85).aspx) that appends the magic `_PyOSSigintEvent` for you when you're doing a wait-first rather than wait-all.

One of the things you can pass to `WaitForMultipleObjects` is a Win32 thread handle, which has the same effect as a `join`, although I'm not sure if there's an easy way to get the thread handle out of a Python thread.

Alternatively, you can manually create some kind of kernel sync object (I don't know the `_winapi` module very well, and I don't have a Windows system, so you'll probably have to read the source yourself, or at least `help` it in the interactive interpreter, to see what wrappers it offers), `WaitForMultipleObjects` on that, and have the thread signal it.

Comment: Isn't your while loop equivalent to not setting a timeout in join?

Comment: I mean, I don't get why is that it is interruptable between each time it does the loop

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde After 0.2 seconds, it gives up trying to `join` and returns `None`. Then we're just executing the bytecodes to return to the top of the loop, and calling `thread.is_alive`, so we're not blocking on anything, and we can be interrupted by the normal CPython code that checks for signals between bytecodes.

Comment: The quick&dirty way is acceptable for me, as the program will always run on foreground. It is not perfect, I get it, but it is good enough. Digging in Python's Windows specific source code or using undocumented internals is too much for my taste. I am a bit puzzled by the fact that the Ctrl+C event will be held until the `join` timeout has expired.

Comment: @Neraste Under the covers, it's… actually I'm not sure whether it's an NT Event, a WM_ message, or even just stuck in a keyboard input queue inside cmd.exe or something. But _whatever_ it is, it's some kind of level-triggered notification, that stays latched until you handle it, not an edge-triggered notification that you can miss.

Comment: Note that looping on `thread.join` can potentially hang the interpreter if "`Thread._wait_for_tstate_lock` [is] interrupted in between acquiring and releasing the sentinel lock" ([issue 21822](https://bugs.python.org/issue21822); as I expplained in message 315815).

Comment: @eryksun From a quick skim, it seems like that’s only an issue if you raise an exception as its waking up, and then try to join it again. In this case, once the KeyboardInterrupt gets raised, we’re out of the loop, and never touching the thread again, so that won’t be a problem. Or is there a deeper problem I’m missing?

Comment: The thread's `join` method gets interrupted unless you disable the default `SIGINT` handler, since the interrupt happens immediately after the interpreter resumes. Then if you try to `join` again it's very likely to hang the next time. I need to try an experiment to see if this affects regular interpreter shutdown that joins all running threads.

Comment: FYI, in Windows the C runtime registers a console control handler, which raises `SIGINT` for `CTRL_C_EVENT` and `SIGBREAK` for all other control events, including `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT`. When the console (conhost.exe, not cmd.exe) processes Ctrl+C, it sends a message to Windows (csrss.exe) that includes the list of processes attached to the console. Windows in turn creates a new control thread in each process that starts at the `CtrlRoutine` function in kernelbase.dll. This walks the registered handlers in LIFO order, until one returns `TRUE` (handled).

Comment: The most reliable way to handle Ctrl+C if the main thread is blocked (generally a bad idea, however) is to use ctypes or PyWin32 to register your own console control handler via `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`. As the last installed handler, it will be called before the C runtime's handler. Since it's on a new thread that acquires the GIL, you can use this function to signal your threads to shutdown gracefully (e.g. `stop.set()`).

Comment: @eryksun But again, this code is never going to `join` again if any exception happens, so that's not going to be a problem, right? Obviously polling has other problems, as I explained in my answer, but the OP seems to be happy with those problems, so the question is whether there's an additional one that I didn't warn him about.

Comment: As long as the thread is shut down before Python exits, the interpreter shouldn't try to `join` it. Whether or not there's a race condition here depends on the overall way the program orchestrates shutdown when Ctrl+C is handled. Like I said, I haven't actually experimented with scenarios that try to make Python hang in this case.

Comment: @eryksun Ah, that's a good point; if the background thread is still in its `sleep(2)` (or, in the OP's presumed real code, in the middle of a `requests.get` or multiplying two giant arrays or whatever), the main thread could easily finish long before it gets back to checking `stop` and exiting, and then (assuming it's not a daemon thread) it will get joined, and that could hang… So this isn't guaranteed to be safe. Do you think I need to put a note about that in the answer?

Comment: @eryksun maybe you can elaborate your idea in a solution post? It does not sound too complicated from here, and since it is a safe way, I am interested.